# Where does Rails' respond_to block parameter get xml, html, json members?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Generating a scaffold like this:

> rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string

creates bits of code that look like this in the controller class:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @user }
end
```

At first I didn't know what this meant, so I went looking and found [this](http://www.tokumine.com/2009/09/13/how-does-respond_to-work-in-the-rails-controllers/),
which I think adequately explains most of it. But format is supposed to end up being a [Responder class](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Responder.html). Well, there doesn't seem to be any xml or html or json members declared in the Responder class. Where do they come from?

PS:

It seems cruel that the scaffold developer would name the block parameter "format" when it ends up being a Responder (and the format information comes from the .html, .xml, .json, or whatever) to make the code sound a bit like English but hinder understanding of what's actually going on. In fact, Responder::respond is defined like so, which seems too coincidental:

```
def respond
  method = "to_#{format}"
  respond_to?(method) ? send(method) : to_format
end
```

But I don't see how the format here (in "to_#{format}") can be related to the block parameter named format. And to be clear, it's NOT an instance variable because it's lacking an @ sign, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the blog explains later, **basically from here the Responder instance handles .html and .xml via method_missing, depending on mime types your rails app can process.** 
One of the nice blogs that describe method_missing is [here](http://www.trottercashion.com/2011/02/08/rubys-define_method-method_missing-and-instance_eval.html).
Basically, the responder's method_missing will get called when js and json methods are invoked. The method_missing of responder class will get the "missing method_name" (that is,  :js or :json symbols) as its first parameter, which will drive its rendering logic.